# Asset Pipeline Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Im just looking for a little clarity to better my understanding of the Rails asset pipeline. I have placed my stylesheets and javascripts within app/assets/javascripts and app/assets/stylesheets. Now i am trying to get these views to render on my page but so far nothing is showing.. I wanted to see if someone could confirm if the following looks correct

In my layouts/application i have

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "fullcalendar" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.rest.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "rails.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>

 <!-- these are needed for the calendar. -->
 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "fullcalendar.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "calendar.js" %>
```

And my index.html.erb looks like

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="/stylesheets/fullcalendar.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/calendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery.rest.js'></script>
```

Am I missing something or just being a real novice ( All constructive criticism welcome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Your layouts/application you just need this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

and in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
you just need:

```
   *=require_self
   *=require_tree .
```

and in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And there's o need to include all the files

You'll have some problems in production if you include js files, to avoid it, you should add such files, **ex: "fullcalendar.js"** in config/production.rb, config.assets.precompile += %W(fullcalendar.js), and then run rake asset:precompile

Comment: thank you, so do i leave 

     <%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>

in the layouts/application? How do i call the javascript in my index page?

Comment: yes, layouts/application,just <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Comment: //= require_tree . in app/assets/javascripts/application.js will handle these cases

Comment: i would put a vote next to your answer but i need a rep of 15 to do that

Comment: another question sorry but if i am in index.html.erb, how does the page know which scripts to use? ie which javascripts to use?

Comment: It uses the application.js and all scripts, which get required in there.

Comment: @richlewis I have tried everything, followed all this steps and one of my new js files is loaded empty

Answer (score 1):

You can see a quick overview in Ryan Bates Video: [#279 Understanding the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline).
For more info go to the [RailsGuide: Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Both helped me a lot.